# Is there a single method/function call for all interactions with all collection in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am fairly new to Meteor so please forgive me if this is a basic and/or stupid question. Each time I create a meteor app, I always end up having to write Collection.insert, .update, .upsert, etc for each collection that I am interacting with. I am looking for a way to have it as one call where I pass in the action, the collection, and the object with the action details.

For example, what I have working right now is being able to pass in the collection name and the object to be inserted and all of my Collection.insert functions are being called with it, along with my .find().

```
'collectionInsert': function(collection,insertObject){
  Mongo.Collection.get(collection).insert(insertObject);
}
```

However, I still have to say ".insert()', so to update a collection, I would have to make a new function and call it collectionUpdate. Which isn't that big of a deal but I would rather have one call that I make for every interaction with the collection and pass it parameters to figure out which collection, which action, and what data.

I'm sure there's some solution that I'm overlooking/too novice to know. Anyone have any pointers to where I should look for the answer?

**My Weak Attempt**

```
'collectionInteraction': function(collection,action,actionObject){
    check(collection, String);
    check(action, String);
    check(actionObject, Object);

    switch(action){

        case 'update':
            Mongo.Collection.get(collection).update(actionObject);
            break;
        case 'insert':
            Mongo.Collection.get(collection).insert(actionObject);
            break;
        case 'upsert':
            Mongo.Collection.get(collection).upsert(actionObject);
            break;
        case 'remove':
            Mongo.Collection.get(collection).remove(actionObject);
            break;
        default:
            console.log("You put the wrong action in ya dingus");

    }

    return 1;
  }
```

with calls anywhere being done like:

```
Meteor.call('collectionInteraction',collection,action,actionObject, function (error, result) {
      if(error){
        ..
      }else {
        ..
      }
    });
```

Comment: could you elaborate what you mean by "having to write Collection.insert, .update, .upsert, etc for each collection that I am interacting with"? where do you need to write that and what for? You aren't looking for `myCollection.insert`, right? which exists for each collection ("myCollection") you create.

Comment: As far as I understand, if I want to have a method that inserts an object into a collection, I have to have it say `_Collection_.insert()`, with _Collection_ being the name of my collection as defined with `Collection = new Mongo.Collection('collection');` and if there are two different collections that I have `insert()` methods for, I would have to do two different methods, as in: `Collection1.insert()` and `Collection2.insert()`.

This becomes even more repetitive when I have to then have `Collection1.updat()` and 'Collection2.update()` and so on.

Comment: yes, but i guess I don't understand what the problem is. Do you want to insert a document into multiple collections in one shot? -- an example of what you want to do would help.

Comment: I'm wanting `collectionInteraction(collection,action,actionObject)` where I can only interact with one function.

Comment: but what's better about `collectionInteraction(collection,action,obj)` compared to `collection.action(obj)`? both these statements have the same elements in them, just arranged differently

Comment: You are 100% right. I may have been overcomplicating things. I was just wanting one method call for all interactions, rather than numerous method calls, so when I looked at my client-side code, it would point back to the same function instead of one for each action.

Comment: perhaps you don't realize that `insert`, `update`, etc. all exist on the client as well. No need to write additional methods.

Comment: You also face the problem that `find` (for example), could take 1, 2, or 3 arguments. And that's before you get to add-on methods like `.fetch()`. `update` takes at least two, not one. I get that you're trying to invent a bespoke abstraction layer but wait until the next time you have a question on Meteor here and your sample code uses it, or until you hire a second developer.

Comment: MongoDB is Schemaless .. Why Dont you have just one collection for all your Data??

Comment: @gatolgaj one collection for all data is a mess. You want multiple collections for each of the logical components of your app

Comment: One collection is always messy, But in this particular usecase it may be useful. other Possibility is to use Meteor Astronomy.